# VB.Net Clear or Reset form BackColor?

Tags: vb.net, forms, reset, backcolor

How do I clear/reset the BackColor of a windows application form? For instance, I have a set of radio buttons, each one changes the color of the background form color, when I reset the radio buttons I would also like to reset the color of the form back to it's original state?

Comment: Is the background color something other than the default to begin with?

Comment: No, It's default to begin with but changes in accordance to the radio button a user clicks. But I managed to get it working with this: Me.BackColor = SystemColors.Control

Answer (score 7):

Simple way :

```
myForm.BackColor = Color.Empty
```

Answer (score 3):

Just set to it [Colors.DefaultBackColor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.defaultbackcolor.aspx).

Comment: I could not get it to work using those methods (I was most likely applying it wrong) but you pointed me in the right direction on MSDN and I found this code to do the job for the time being until I become better at VB.Net: Me.BackColor = SystemColors.Control Thanks again guys!

Comment: @William Mc: Colors.DefaultBackColor = SystemColors.Control so it should work :)